# Text overflowing from html button seemingly in contrast to applied styling

Tags: html, css, button

I just cannot figure out why the text in this button is not wrapping to the next line. Instead it is getting cut off at the end. Here is the styling:

```
#find-attach-all-content-container input[type="button"] {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #fd902a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #b6b6b6 1px;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<input type="button" class="attach-btn" value="Attach to Response" onclick="postConditionFindCure( <?php echo get_the_ID() ?> );">
```

Comment: I should add that wordwrap: normal did not help either.

Comment: Please read my answer, it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

You should add:

```
white-space: normal;
```

The default value for `white-space` is set not to wrap for input elements.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought, it's not possible!

Comment: It works because you removed the `height`. Otherwise, it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/23x3pL9f/2/

Comment: I would go with this one with precaution... :|

Comment: @ Melancia: I didn't remove the height and it worked... Perhaps this is different depending on the browswer. I am using chrome

Comment: I'm also using Chrome. Check the jsFiddle link I've posted. It contains the original styles you posted + the rule in this answer. If you keep the `height` rule, there's no possible way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: visible` will work with text just if the container element doesn't have a static `height` defined.

Also, you will need to overwrite the default value of `white-space`, setting it to `normal`, otherwise the text will wrap at the end of its container element.

So, you would need to change your styles by removing the `height` and setting the `white-space`:

```
#find-attach-all-content-container input[type="button"] {
    width: 60px;
    /* height: 60px; */
    background-color: #fd902a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #b6b6b6 1px;
    /* Added */
    white-space: normal;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/23x3pL9f/4/)

[CSS-Tricks: overflow](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)

[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use carriage return characters to break the line:

```
<input type="button" value="Really&#x00A;Tall&#x00A; Button">
```

Comment: Height would be according to how many lines you break the text. Not constructive.

Comment: The purpose of the site is to provide **correct** answers to a question, **respecting** what the OP has proposed, unless it's something totally wrong. Their code mentions `height` in the styles, so your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @Jay Just to clarify MelanciaUK's point, your solution will work with the default style, but not with the style supplied by OP.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Are you telling me that sometimes when people post their css it does not need to be changed to get the fix to work? i agree he put height 60,  but lets be honest here people add styles and we change them with our answers, if we was to keep everyones css as is then we would not be able to solve there issue. Is that not correct? Ive accepted my downvote however this answer is still an option and i beleive MelanciaUK has been picky.

Comment: It's not about being picky. It's about SO recommendations. Make your answer complete then. Mention that for this solution to work, the OP will need to change the styles. That's all.